# Profile Model with Devise Users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to create a separate Profile model for Devise Users with things such as location, biography, blah, blah, blah.  The problem is that I can't get it to save to the database.

My users are called "artists".

```
### /routes.rb ###

get 'artists/:id/new_profile' => 'artists/profiles#new', as: :profile
post 'artists/:id/new_profile' => 'artists/profiles#create'

### artists/profiles_controller.rb ###

class Artists::ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_artist!

  def new
    @artist = current_artist
    @profile = ArtistProfile.new
  end

  def create
    @artist = current_artist
    @profile = ArtistProfile.new(profile_params)
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to current_artist
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end

### /artist.rb ###

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable
  has_one :artist_profile, dependent: :destroy

### /artist_profile.rb ###

class ArtistProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  validates :artist_id, presence: true
end

### /views/artists/profiles/new.html.erb ###

<%= form_for(@profile, url: profile_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :biography, "biography", class: "label" %>
    <%= f.text_area :biography, autofocus: true , class: "text-field" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :location, "location", class: "label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :location, class: "text-field" %>
  </div>
  ...
  ...
  ...
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "create profile", class: "submit-button" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialise the profile using the `current_artist` object.

```
class Artists::ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_artist!

  def new
    @artist = current_artist
    @profile = @artist.build_profile
  end

  def create
    @artist = current_artist
    @profile = @artist.build_profile(profile_params)
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to current_artist
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Update:

To use this example your association should be like

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, class_name: ArtistProfile
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the artist_id for the profile before attempting to save.

```
@profile = ArtistProfile.new(profile_params, artist_id: @artist.id)
```

or

```
@profile = ArtistProfile.new(profile_params)
@profile.artist_id = @artist.id
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you are missing the profile_params method.

```
private 

def profile_params
        params.require(:profile).permit(:biography, :location)
end
```